# Proving (or disproving) an algebraic identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

It seems like a simple thing, but I am stucked on that for some time and decided ask for help...!

I see on a work that

\begin{align}&\dfrac{x-x^*}{x}(a-bxy-ax)+\dfrac{y-y^*}{y}(bxy-(a+c)y)\\&=b(x-x^*)(y-y^*)-a\dfrac{(x-x^*)^2}{xx^*}-b(x-x^*)(y-y^*)\\
&=-a\dfrac{(x-x^*)^2}{xx^*}\end{align}

where $a=-by^*+\dfrac{a}{x^*}$ and $a+c=bx^*$.

The cases I tried worked, but I'm definitely not getting algebraic development. Since now, grateful.

======

Please, see Blue's comment for a simplification (which I unfortunately didn't manage to continue until the end).

Comment: Hopefully, it's clear that the third line follows from the second, so the problem reduces to showing that the second follows from the first. Note that substituting $a+c\to b x^*$ in the second term of the first line readily gives the first term of the second line; so the problem reduces to showing that the last two terms of the second line follow from the first term of the first line. (Conveniently, all of these terms have a factor of $x-x^*$ that you can therefore effectively ignore.) ... Does that help?

Comment: @Blue really thank you, but unfortunately I've already tried this... (I didn't write before because I thought I might be hindering some thought)... And I did not could get the answer from that... Thank you

Comment: For future reference: Please always include all the work you've done, so that people (like me! :) don't waste time duplicating your effort. "Hindering thought" isn't a concern; if people don't want to be distracted by your work, they can ignore it. ... Be that as it may ... Are you convinced that "all you have to do" is show the equivalence of these two expressions? $$\frac1x(a-bxy-ax) \qquad\text{and}\qquad -a\;\frac{x-x^\star}{xx^\star}-b(y-y^\star)$$ If so, have you considered multiplying-out each of them and seeing how  they compare in light of the relation $a=-by^\star+\frac{a}{x}$?

Comment: Now everything is closed! Thank you very much. You talking, I got a better look. Thank you also for the advice. If you add your comments to an answer, I’d be happy to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Since I duplicated your own effort, you should put your work into an answer so that we can upvote your final success. Cheers!